# Connecting to Github from server

Tags: ssh, git, authentication

I am trying to connect to Github from a server running Jenkins.

To do this, I'm copying my public key from another server, into the authorized_keys on the new server.

All I'm getting is the following error:

```
git ls-remote -h git@github.com:Company/client.git HEAD
Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address 'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' to the list of known hosts.
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

All I did was this:

1. Go into the .ssh directory on the user account I want, on the old server
2. Copy the public key, in id_rsa.pub.
3. Log into the new server, go into /root/.ssh, and put that key into "authorized_keys"
4. Attempt the above command.

What am I doing wrong? My suspicion is that I'm not copying the key to the correct location, and that in actuality I want to have the entire id_rsa.pub as well as the private key up there, and I'm actually trying to copy a user setting - but I'm not quite sure.

How do I access github from this new server?

Answer (score 3):

In order to connect to github you need the *private key* on the new server. You could copy the *private key* to the new machine but I would advise you to not do this. Instead generate a new pair of ssh keys and add the *public key* to your Github account under https://github.com/settings/ssh.

Please read about public/private key systems because from your question you seem to lack some basic understanding.